# why are assets gems required when assets:precompile has been done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, ruby-on-rails-3.2, therubyracer

given the gemfile below, and that the assets are precompiled and uploaded manually, why does the command

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
```

cause ruby to complain that the gems in "assets" are not installed ? I thought that assets were only used in production or where a precompile was not done ?

The problem is that rubyracer, which seems to be required by less/sass does not compile on the target architecture (an arm processor)

```
# gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '>= 3.2.8'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '>= 3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'uuidtools'
gem 'simple_form', '>= 2.0.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.12.2'
gem 'json'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '>= 1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 2.11.0'
  gem 'annotate'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', '>= 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
  gem 'will_paginate'
  gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
  gem 'less-rails-fontawesome'
end

group :test do
   gem 'capybara', '>= 1.1.2'
   gem 'rb-fchange'
   gem 'rb-notifu'
   gem 'factory_girl_rails'
   gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Comment: see this link http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: thanks, I did follow most of the instructions there, especially the local precompile. I still get the error

    rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
    Could not find gem 'therubyracer (>= 0) ruby' in the gems     available on this machine.
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 1):

try this,  gem 'therubyracer' write out side the assets.

```
group :production do
 gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

then bundle install

Comment: as I mentioned in the original question, my goal is _not_ to have the need for rubyracer in production, as it doesn't compile on the target processor (arm).

Comment: which rake version you used?
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:schema:load

Comment: Many thanks for helping. 

rake, version 0.9.2.2. 

Your command still gives the same error. (tries to load rubyracer)

Comment: urgh. even _bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=production --without development test assets_ gives the same error